# How to write an OpenAPI schema for a nested arrays with mixed type values?

Tags: swagger, openapi

My API returns the response in following format:

```json
[
  [
    "Time",
    "Attempts",
    "Successes",
    "Failures",
    "BookabilityRatio"
  ],
  [
    "2022-07-30",
    995935,
    734009,
    61926,
    73.70
  ],
  [
    "2022-07-31",
    949576,
    683740,
    265836,
    72.00
  ]
]
```

It's a list or list or array or array where each element has a different data type.
How to create an OpenAPI schema for this response?

Comment: This will not work. I guess this is data from csv file with n lines. This means you will have n nested array with mixed data types (string, integer, number).

Hopefully you are able to transform the data. e.g.:

```json
[
  {
    "Time": "2022-07-30",
    "Attempts": 995935
  },
  {
    "Time": "2022-07-31",
    "Attempts": 949576
  }
]

```

Answer (score 1):

An array of mixed-type arrays can be defined as follows:

```yaml
type: array
items:
  type: array
  items: {}   # An empty schema means "any type"
```

Or if the values are limited to just strings and numbers (i.e. no booleans, objects or more nested arrays) AND you use OpenAPI 3.x, you could use:

```yaml
# OpenAPI 3.1 version
type: array
items:
  type: array
  items:
    type: [string, integer, number]

# OpenAPI 3.0 version
type: array
items:
  type: array
  items:
    anyOf:
      - type: string
      - type: integer
      - type: number
```